# Does Nephalem Valor Persist Across Game Exit

Tags: diablo-iii

I started D3 and logged into the game. My level 60(7) Barbarian was selected and I quick-joined a game with a level 60(4) character. Only the two of us were in the game. After some game-play, I had 4 or 5 Nephalem Valor (NV). I then returned to town and exited the game.

A while later (possibly less than 30 minutes), I started the game again, logged in and quick-joined the same party, still with only the two of us present. I don't recall my NV buff at this point. I bannered to the other player just as an elite was being killed I think. A minute or so later I noticed I had 5 NV stacks, with 28 minutes remaining. The only explanation is that NV stack persist across exiting the game?

After playing further in the party, I left the game and the party and joined a normal public game. At this point, there were no NV stacks.

Comment: It shouldn't, but it sounds like it might if you rejoin the current game. Would make sense.

Comment: a wild guess would be: NV stacks are "saved" if you exit and enter the exact same game. So if you exit one game and join the other one, you will lose all your NV stacks

Comment: Yes, that would seem to be the case. However, I would have thought that actually exiting/quitting the game would have terminated all stacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since patch 1.0.5 (released on Oct. 15, 2012):

"Nephalem Valor stacks are now restored whenever a player rejoins the last multiplayer game he/she was disconnected from"

Full patch notes: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/patch-notes/1-0-5